# How to make app works also after closed

Tags: android, bluetooth

tks your previous post, I'd able to create an app that disable Bluetooth connection, when disconnected from any device. All works fine but I'm still facing with a problem...it works only if the app is open. How can I get the possibility to make it works even it is closed?

Please find below the code used for the main Activity:

```
package com.myapps.connectionmanager;

import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.ListPreference;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.util.Log;

public class QuickPrefsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "QuickPrefsActivity";
    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 12;
    private static boolean state = false;
    private BluetoothAdapter adapter;
    private SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;
    private Boolean getPrefValue;
    private int getTimePrefValue;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

        //controllo esistenza BT
        setBluetoothAdapter();

        IntentFilter filter1 = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED);
        IntentFilter filter2 = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED);
        IntentFilter filter3 = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED);
        this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter1);
        this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter2);
        this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter3);


    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        // Unregister broadcast listeners
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, 0, 0, "Show current settings");
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case 0:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, ShowSettingsActivity.class));
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void setBluetoothAdapter() {
        // Getting the Bluetooth adapter
        adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        Log.i(TAG,
                "\nAdapter: " + adapter.toString() + "\n\nName: "
                        + adapter.getName() + "\nAddress: "
                        + adapter.getAddress());
        // Check for Bluetooth support in the first place
        // Emulator doesn't support Bluetooth and will return null
        if (adapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth NOT supported. Aborting.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
                }

            //The BroadcastReceiver that listens for bluetooth broadcasts
    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                Log.i(TAG,"Device found");
            }
            else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
                Log.i(TAG,"Device is now connected");
            }
            else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
                Log.i(TAG,"Done searching");
            }
            else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED.equals(action)) {
                Log.i(TAG,"Device is about to disconnect");
            }
            else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
                Log.i(TAG,"Device has disconnected");
                switchOFF_BT();
            }           
        }
    };

    private static boolean blueToothON_OFF_Status() {
        BluetoothAdapter bluetooth = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (!bluetooth.isEnabled()) {
            Log.i(TAG,"Bluetooth is Disable...");
            state = true;
        } else if (bluetooth.isEnabled()) {
//          String address = bluetooth.getAddress();
//          String name = bluetooth.getName();
//          Log.i(TAG,name + " : " + address);
            state = false;
        }
        return state;
        }

    private void switchOFF_BT(){
        if (!blueToothON_OFF_Status()){
            adapter.disable();
        }
    }

}
```

Tks a lot

Comment: Maybe use a service rather then an activity as it can run in background.

Comment: It's calld "service"

Comment: @Neo78 check my answer and let me know if it helped, if it did mark it as a correct, otherwise I'll update my answer.

Comment: Solved your question? Or shall I update the my answer?

Comment: @Skizo Hi Skizo, first of all, many many thanks for your help! It was very useful to drive me on the right way. I'm trying to understand how to put into my service class the method about the broadcast receiver from my activity and then I'll solved completely the problem.  I've just tried but I faced some problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to make app works also after closed

You can do it with [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html). With it you can run your app when you have closed it.

Here's a perfect example to how to do it [Android Services Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_services.htm)

### Little tips

So when you have your `Service class` created on your `MainActivity` you can add those methods.

```
// Method to start the service
public void startService(View view) {
   startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyService.class));
}

// Method to stop the service
public void stopService(View view) {
    stopService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyService.class));
}
```

Also don't forget to add this on your `manifest.xml`

```
<service android:name=".MyService" />
```

And here's another [Example of service](http://javatechig.com/android/android-service-example).

Hope it helps, if you need more help let me know, and I'll help you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some great resources regarding what you're trying to do:

Creating Background Services:
https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html

Running in a Background Service:
http://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/index.html

I would also take a look at the best practices section